# ArrayList of JComboBoxes causing JComboBoxes to lock to each other

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox

This is the problem I'm having: I have an `ArrayList` of 5 `JComboBox`'s. These `JComboBox`'s each contain the same five options: `"1", "2", "3", "4", and "5"`. I then add the `ArrayList` of `JComboBox`'s to a `JFrame` via a `for` loop. However, for some odd reason, whenever I select an option in one of the `JComboBox`'s, the rest of the `JComboBox`'s also select that reason. **This first screenshot is of the** `JFrame` **in its state when first executed**:[image: screenshot1]

**This is a screenshot of the user selecting another menu item:**[image: screenshot2]

**And this third screenshot shows that ALL the `JComboBox`'s changed to the selected input.** [image: screenshot3]

This is my code:

```
class Foo {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Add person(s)");
    ArrayList<JComboBox> comboArray = new ArrayList<JComboBox>();

    String[] floors = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(floors);

public void go() {
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        comboArray.add(new JComboBox<String>(model)); //Adds numbers 1-5 to a new JComboBox, and the JComboBox is then added to comboArray
        frame.add(comboArray.get(x)); //Adds each JComboBox to the frame
    }
    frame.setResizable(false);   
    ...
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main (String [] args) {
    go();
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
comboArray.add(new JComboBox<String>(model));
```

You are adding the same `ComboBoxModel` to each combo box.

You need to create a separate model for each combo box.

So the code inside the loop should be:

```
DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(floors);
comboArray.add(new JComboBox<String>(model));
```

Now each combo box contains a separate model, but each model contains the same values.